# .ARI File Format

Tags: images, camera, tags, raw

1. What is the structure of .ari (arriraw) file extension?

   I only know the header of this structure which is  **41 52 52 49** (ARRI).
2. What are tags of this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is the structure of .ari (arriraw) file extension?

ARRIRAW is an open format and ARRI have submitted the specification to the Society of Motion Picture & Television Engineers (SMPTE)'s website:

> We've successfully submitted two SMPTE Registered Disclosure Documents
>   (RDDs) on ARRIRAW:
>
> RDD 30:2014: ARRIRAW Image File Structure and Interpretation
>   Supporting Deferred Demosaicing to a Logarithmic Encoding  RDD
>   31:2014: Deferred Demosaicing of an ARRIRAW Image File to a Wide-Gamut
>   Logarithmic Encoding.
>
> These documents are available from the Society of Motion Picture &
>   Television Engineers (SMPTE)'s website at https://www.smpte.org.

Source [ARRIRAW FAQ](https://www.arri.com/en/learn-help/learn-help-camera-system/frequently-asked-questions/arriraw-faq#accordion-44232)

---

#### What are tags of this extension?

I assume that by tags you are referring to metadata.

> **What metadata is recorded along the image in an ARRIRAW file?**
>
> The metadata contains all camera settings, production notes,
>   optionally scene and take information, camera tilt and roll and lens
>   metadata (if an LDS lens/camera was used). Tilt, roll and lens
>   information is recorded for each frame individually, so it is possible
>   to track the exact timing, e.g. when the focus pulls away from one
>   actor to an object in the back.
>
> That data can be accessed and extracted using ARRI Meta Extract (AME)
>   or the ARRIRAW Converter (ARC).

Source [ARRIRAW FAQ](https://www.arri.com/en/learn-help/learn-help-camera-system/frequently-asked-questions/arriraw-faq#accordion-44246)

Comment: For 200 $ I have to purchase this documentary. is there any other link on which it is free?

Comment: @Saurav I've no idea.